# Unit-testing Injector after manually injecting Router (APP_INITIALIZER)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine, angular-router

In `app.module.ts`, I have the following:

```
{provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: appServiceFactory, multi: true, deps: [AppService]}
```

I was trying to add `Router` dependency in `AppService`, but I was getting the following error:

```
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef...
```

I added `Injector` to my `AppService` constructor, and manually added `Router`:

```
private get router() {
    return this.injector.get(Router);
}
```

I successfully use it like so:

```
this.router.navigate([ routePath ], {queryParams: {type: paramType}})
    .then(() => {
        return resolve();
    });
```

===

For testing, I added `Injector` to providers, and also stubbed the `Router`:

```
let injector: Injector;

const routerStub = {navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')};

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [],
        providers: [
            AppService,
            ...,
            Injector,
            {provide: Router, useValue: routerStub}
        ]
    });

    injector = TestBed.get(Injector);

    spyOn(injector, 'get').and.returnValue(routerStub);
});
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR LOG: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined', '; Zone:', 'ProxyZone', '; Task:', 'jasmine.onComplete', '; Value:', TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

I tried replacing `Router` in providers with `RouterTestingModule` in imports, but still the same error.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

===

Edit: Added `routerStub`

Edit 2: Resolution

Thanks to @Inge Olaisen's input, I was able to resolve the error. Answer(s):

## 1 - Stub router with `useClass` (w/ promise) instead of `useValue`

```
class MockRouter {
    navigate(routePath: any[], params: any) {
        return new Promise<boolean>(resolve => resolve(true));
    }
}

...

{provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter}

...

injector = TestBed.get(Injector);

spyOn(injector, 'get').and.returnValue(routerStub); // Not needed anymore
```

## 2 - Use `RouterTestingModule`

```
let injector: Injector;
let router: Router;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            RouterTestingModule
        ],
        providers: [
            AppService,
            ...,
            Injector,
            {provide: Router, useValue: routerStub}
        ]
    });

    injector = TestBed.get(Injector);
    router = TestBed.get(Router);

    spyOn(router, 'navigate').and.returnValue(new Promise<boolean>(resolve => resolve(true)))
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you didn’t provide any information about your routerstub, or how it setup, but what you need to do is to mock the return value to be a promise. Because it expects to get one, but it doesn’t get anything, thus it is undefined.

In other words .navigate doesn’t return a this.router.

You could try:

```
class MockRoute {
navigate(routePath: any[], params: any) {
return new Promise();
}}
```

Full disclaimer, I’m not used to creating promises, I’m used to the observable way, so you need to probably mock the new Promise part correctly.

I do however recommend you to use TypeMoq. Then you would just use:
    const router = TypeMock.Mock.ofType();
    router.setup(r => r.navigate).returns(()=> new Promise());

Then you use router.object instead of the routerStub, but it would be:
    { provide: Router, useFactory: ()=> router.object }
instead of 
    {provide: Router, useValue: routerStub}